# Discrepancy with differentiation in Fourier space

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, dft

I am solving differential equations in Fourier space using Matlab. However, I got a problem: after differentiating my real signal I get complex answer (which is incorrect).

Consider an example with diffirentiation over `x` (multiplication by `ik` in fourier space):

```
 a=rand(6,1).';
 fr=fftshift(-3:1:2);
 ifft(1i*fr.*fft(a))
```

The output is complex. I figured out why it happens: our frequency spectrum is `-3,-2,-1,0,1,2`. So, there is no pair for the highest frequency (we have -3, but don't have 3). I am wondering how to fix it.

If we think about it, there is technically non-zero contribution from the highest frequency. If the fourier amplitude on the frequency -3 is `c0`, that means, that in reality we have amplitude `c0/2` on frequencies -3 and 3, so that after differentiation we get:

```
(c0/2)*i*(-k)*exp(-ikx)+(c0/2)*i*(k)*exp(ikx)=kc0*sin(kx)
```

I am curious, how to implement correct differentiation. My problem is 2D, so that I use fft2 and ifft2. But problem is of the same origin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take three things into account:

- Differentiating in time corresponds to **multiplying the DFT** by `1-exp(-1j*2*pi/N*fr)`, where `N` is the signal period and `fr = 0:N-1` are the frequency samples. This stems from the time-shift property of the DFT (see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem)).
- This differentiation should be **circular** (see above link), because the DFT inherently assumes that the time signal is periodic. So the first differentiated sample in the time domain will be `a(1)-a(N)`, the second will be `a(2)-a(1)`, etc.
- You may get a very small imaginary part due to **floating-point accuracy**.

So, the code should be:

```
a = rand(6,1).';
N = numel(a);
fr = 0:N-1;
a_diff_fr = ifft((1-exp(-1j*2*pi/N*fr)).*fft(a));
```

Check:

```
>> a_diff_fr % imag part should be small
a_diff_fr =
  Columns 1 through 5
  -0.5490 - 0.0000i   0.3169 - 0.0000i  -0.5662 + 0.0000i   0.6851 + 0.0000i  -0.5155 - 0.0000i
  Column 6
   0.6287 + 0.0000i

>> real(a_diff_fr) % real part only
ans =
   -0.5490    0.3169   -0.5662    0.6851   -0.5155    0.6287

>> a([1 2:N])-a([N 1:N-1]) % circular differentiation
ans =
   -0.5490    0.3169   -0.5662    0.6851   -0.5155    0.6287
```

Comment: Thanks! I always treated frequencies in the domain [-N,N]. This method might work. I just don't understand, why do you have to multiply it by `1-exp(i*2pi*n/N)`. Do you have a link where this is explained?

Comment: @Mikhail See the link in the answer. It tells you the DFT of the (circularly) shifted version of the signal. To differentiate you need 1 minus that

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing a 2 pi in there.  Here an example using `x = 2 cos(2*pi*t)`

```
Tp = 10; % sample length
deltaTime = Tp / 200; % time step
time = 0:deltaTime:Tp; % time
x = 2*cos(2*pi*time); % function
plot(time, x)
fMax = 1/deltaTime/2; % maximum frequency
fMin = 1/Tp; % lowest observable frequency
xfft = fft(x) ./ (length(time)/ 2); % fft scaled to original amplitude, in case you want to plot it.
freq = -1*fMax:fMin:fMax; % frequencies of the fft
xd_fft = xfft .* fftshift(freq) * 1i*2*pi; % note the extra 2 pi in here.
xd = ifft(xd_fft, 'symmetric') * (length(xd_fft)/ 2); % reverse the scaling and take the ifft.
xd2 = -4*pi*sin(2*pi*time);
plot(time, xd2, '.')
```

The equation that I have for doing this is:

x(t) = Xe^(iwt) and

x'(t) = iwXe^(iwt)

Recall that w = 2*pi*f.

If I knew how to use greek symbols on SO I would.  But I think you get what I'm saying.

Comment: I just tried to provide as simple as possible example. In your code you used symmetric option in ifft function, that eliminates complex number in the answer. Not sure the answer is actually correct, you might just through away high frequency.

Comment: And If I just missed 2*pi I would not get complex answer instead of real

Comment: I actually checked: 'symmetric' option eliminated the highest frequency.

Comment: But this is what you actually need to do, so technically your answer is correct too. I posted my explanation just in case

Comment: @MikhailGenkin you are correct that the `symmetric` option cleans up the answer because it forces Matlab to use the symmetric form.  However your original equation is missing the `2 pi`.  Without that your derivative is wrong.  To test it just change the 10th line of my example.  If you remove `2 pi` from that line the answer is wrong.

Comment: I agree. I didn't include `2pi` factor, because it is irrelevant here. I just considered [0;2pi] interval

Answer (score 0):

Luis Mendo suggested correct solution to my problem. I also figured out how to fix my approach: the think is, that sinusoid component is always zero on the high frequency, only cosinusoidal harmonic is visible:

```
signal=sin(2.*(linspace(0,2*pi*(1-1/4),4)));
q=fftshift(fft(signal))./4
```

Here q is zero. But if do it with cos(2x) signal:

```
signal=cos(2.*(linspace(0,2*pi*(1-1/4),4)));
q=fftshift(fft(signal))./4
```

Here q(1)=1. So, in my approach I have to set imaginary part of the highest harmonic to 0 after multiplication by `ik`, as long as sinusoidal harmonic is invisible. As Matt suggested, one can simply use 'symmetric' option in ifft routine